# CLI python. click vs fire

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль

У python есть две известные библиотеки: [click](https://github.com/pallets/click), [fire](https://github.com/google/python-fire). Какие есть плюсы и минусы у одной и у второй?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На хабре [есть](https://habr.com/ru/post/466999/) статья с обзором

## Краткое резюме

### [Fire](https://github.com/google/python-fire)

Если вы стараетесь писать код по минимуму — начните с [Fire](https://github.com/google/python-fire).

> Тоже недавно выбирали CLI. Остановились на Click. Смотрели на Fire. Он подойдет когда написал приложение, а тебе, вдруг, сказали сделать для него CLI по быстроляну :)
> Что касается лично моего опыта, то мне очень понравился fire, так как он прост и имеет низкий порог вхождения в отличие, например, от click. Help неплох, но и не что-то из ряда вон выходящее. Я бы охарактеризовал fire как *argparse с человеческим лицом*

### [Click](https://github.com/pallets/click)

Относительно fire -- монстр. Но для сложных интерфейсов незаменим. Я с ним не работал. Комментарий из статьи, который может быть полезен:

> Приходилось плотно работать с click, на память вот какие есть минусы:
>
> - нельзя задать аналог nargs='+' для опциональных аргументов. Только позиционные аргументы можно передавать в неопределённом количестве. В какой-то степени это исключает ambiguous поведение при смешивании команд и опций, но на самом деле всё решаемо и это недоработка, которую не будут исправлять. https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/484
> - проблема с chain, а именно: нельзя использовать одновременно позиционные и опциональные аргументы в chain-командах. Это неисправимая проблема из-за которой хотят вообще убрать поддержку chain (что сломает много программ, завязанных на эту функциональность) https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/1269
>   встроенный help криво отображает позиционные аргументы (об этом есть в документации)
> - встроенный help никак явно не отображает, что опциональный аргумент является multiple, если он таковой (multiple=True)
> - Нет поддержки mutually exclusive групп и не будет: https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/257
>
> Это то, что вспомнил, есть ещё разные подводные камни, на которые натыкаешься если используешь click на полную мощность. В остальном это лучшая библиотека для создания cli на мой взгляд.

### Другие

С другими фреймворками Вы можете ознакомиться в статье

Answer (score 1):

У fire функционала поменьше, чем у click, да и с API иногда проблемы возникают. Подробнее здесь: https://habr.com/ru/post/466999/

Comment: Я это видел. Это не кажется ответом на вопрос. Это просто ссылка. Ответом на вопрос будет пофункциональное сравнение двух утилит.

Comment: @hedgehogues, пофункциональное сравнение - это целая статья. Для данного сайта это будет слишком объемный ответ (это будет скорее формат хабра как раз). По вопросу - попробуйте обе, выберите какая понравится. Лично для меня click более очевиден и удобен.

Comment: @hedgehogues, кстати, если вы эту ссылку видели, стоит указать в вопросе, что конкретно вас в той статье не устраивает. Там плюсы и минусы рассмотрены. А пока - голосую за закрытие вопроса как слишком общего.